# OpenGL empty project uses too much CPU

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I have created a simple OpenGL program, following the LearnOpenGL tutorial. It just creates a window and fills it with a color. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

int main() {
    // Initialize GLFW
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Create GLFW Window
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Golden Retriever", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // Initialize GLAD
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Render Loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        processInput(window);

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}
```

The program works perfectly, however it uses way too much CPU (around 50%). Is it something in Visual Studio properties, or am i just doing something wrong in my code?

Comment: Why is this "too much"? Why should it _not_ use that much CPU time?

Comment: Could it be that you have turned off vsync?

Comment: @derhass  For this example, if vsync is turned on, and the display has 60Hz (or even 144Hz), then the CPU usage should be really low (if it isn't a really old CPU), but if it is turned off then the CPU usage will become hight until the driver calls, or GPU becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable **vsync** with `glfwSwapInterval(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The way Windows measures CPU time falls flat on its face for processes that spend most of their time blocking (=waiting) on kernel calls. What happens in your case is, that in order to V-Sync your program has to wait for the vertical retrace to happen. That usually involves waiting for a synchronization object that's locked from kernel context.d

In order to make Windows measure consumed CPU time accurately add a `Sleep(1)` right before the buffer swap call.